# CodeIgniter: Undefined property: stdClass::$CategoryID

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm inner joining two databases together here, when using the separate views individually they work fine, so do the databases, I think the cause of this is the inner join, but putting the query directly into phpmyadmin and replacing the $categoryID with a number works.

Some rows load, such as the images, but joined variables are undefined, What is causing the variables to be undefined?

Model:

```
function DisplayBySpecificCategory($categoryID) 
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM CIUploads
                               INNER JOIN CIUsers ON CIUploads.UserID = CIUsers.UserID
                               WHERE CIUploads.UploadCategoryID = $categoryID 
                               ORDER BY CIUploads.UploadTime DESC");
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
function SpecificCategory()
    {
        $categoryID=$this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->load->model('Previews_model');
        $this->load->model('Category_model');      
        $this->load->view('../includes/header.php'); 
        $data['category'] = $this->Category_model->GenerateCategoryHeader($categoryID);
        $data['allwork'] = $this->Previews_model->DisplayBySpecificCategory($categoryID);
        $this->load->view('headers/Specific_category_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('previews/Previews_view', $data); 
        $this->load->view('../includes/footer.php');
    }
```

Header view:

```
<?php foreach ($category as $value2){ ?> 
    <header style="background-color:#<?php echo $value2->CategoryColor ?>">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="page-intro">
                        <h1 class="inverted text-center"><?php echo $value2->CategoryTitle ?></h1>
                        <p class="inverted text-center"><?php echo $value2->CategoryDescription ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
<?php } ?>
```

Previews view:

```
                <?php
                    if($value->UploadCategoryID == 2){
                        echo '<video muted class="video-responsive fit-centered">'; 
                            echo '<source src="'.base_url("/public/uploads/works")."/".$value->UploadedAt.'" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.'; 
                        echo '</video>'; 
                    }

                     else if($value->UploadCategoryID == 3){ 
                        echo '<iframe class="fit-centered" src="http://'.$value->UploadedAt.'" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
                     }

                    else{
                        echo '<img class="img-responsive fit-centered" src="'.base_url("/public/uploads/works")."/".$value->UploadedAt.'" alt="'.$value->UploadTitle.'">';
                    } ?>

                <div class="overlay">
                    <p>
                        <a href="<?php echo site_url("/Work_controller/ViewWork/".$value->UploadID) ?>" class="inverted"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-3x ease-color"></i></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="hovereffect-information no-bounding">
                <span class="category-tab pull-right text-center inverted" style="background-color:#<?php echo $value->CategoryColor ?>"><i class="fa <?php echo $value->CategoryIcon ?>"></i></span>
                <p class="pull-left no-bounding text-uppercase preview-info"><?php echo $value->UploadTitle ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url("/Profile_controller/ViewProfile/".$value->UserID)?>"><img class="img-responsive small-profile-img pull-right hover-dim fit-centered" src="<?php echo base_url("/public/uploads/profile-images/")."/".$value->ProfileImg ?>" alt="<?php echo $value->Username ?>"/></a>
                <p class="pull-left no-bounding text-uppercase preview-info">
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url("/Category_controller/ViewCategory/".$value->CategoryID) ?>"></a> 
                    <span class="preview-span"> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <?php echo $value->UploadViews ?> </span> |
                    <span class="preview-span"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <?php echo $value->UploadLikes ?> </span> |
                    <span class="preview-span"> <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> <?php echo $value->UploadComments ?> </span> 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$CategoryIcon
>
> Filename: previews/Previews_view.php
>
> Line Number: 31
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /web/stud/u1263522/cmw/application/views/previews/Previews_view.php
>   Line: 31 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   /web/stud/u1263522/cmw/application/controllers/Views_controller.php
>   Line: 64 Function: view
>
> File: /web/stud/u1263522/cmw/index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: Sorry in advance for the large amount of code here, I've looked long an hard at all of it and nothings appearing obvious to me

Answer (score 0):

In the question you have mentioned : Undefined property: stdClass::**$CategoryID**

whereas the error shows : Undefined property: stdClass::**$CategoryIcon**

If $CategoryIcon is undefined it means that you do not have a column called CategoryIcon in any of your tables.

Can you mention the details of the tables?

It is always a good practice to mention the column names in the query instead of *.

Answer (score 0):

add your loading model before called in Controller , Check name is correct , Make sure that some name in (model = Class)

```
$this->load->model('model_name'); //
```

Or in Confige.php